# Ant build scripts totally hangs, with no messages in console

Tags: eclipse, exception, ant, console, freeze

I have build.xml for my project, but even this small piece of code

```
  <target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>
```

It doesn't run

Console is empty but process is active. I still can terminate it over STOP button

In same time I cannot debug it as well, same stuff active process no output in console and I can wait forever! Any ideas?

- JDK 1.6.0_14
- Eclipse 3.5.1

***Edited*:     Thank to Peter's Loron question I checked workspace log file MyWorkspace/.metadata/.log
There I saw error message I googled it and found that this happening because location of my Eclipse changed, but path to ANT jars remains old.
TO Fix that you have to go Preferences->Ant->Runtime and click Restore Default it will pickup new jar location and warn you about absence of tools.jar, copy it from somewhere and drop it in same folder where other ant jars.**

Comment: Does the ant script run from the command line? Any errors in the system log or eclipse log?

Comment: Which operating system and where is the file being ran from? My line of thought is if you are running on widows vista or 7, windows may be blocking it because of the location of the files. I don't know how windows vista/7 would, react to Ant in, say, `c:\javaProjects\` unless you set the required permissions on the `javaProjects` folder.

Comment: Are you executing the build script from inside Eclipse, or independently from the command shell? Have you tried executing ant with the '-v' option given (for diagnostic output), and added an <echo message="Build is '${build}'" /> statement to trace the execution itself?

Comment: Are you running any of these from a network drive?

Comment: Running it from Eclipse, Eclipse and Project on Drive C of My laptop, Laptop is Win7 64Bit.
Ant Error is:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.ui 4 120 2010-03-17 14:27:31.484
!MESSAGE Error logged from Ant UI: 
!STACK 0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.RemoteAntBuildListener$ServerConnection.run(RemoteAntBuildListener.java:95)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edited: Thank to Peter's Loron question I checked workspace log file MyWorkspace/.metadata/.log There I saw error message I googled it and found that this happening because location of my Eclipse changed, but path to ANT jars remains old.

TO Fix that you have to go Preferences->Ant->Runtime and click Restore Default it will pickup new jar location and warn you about absence of tools.jar, copy it from somewhere and drop it in same folder where other ant jars.

Comment: I got the warning about tools.jar, ignored it and this still worked in Eclipse 2018-12

Answer (score 8):

Here is yet another possible fix:

- Go to `Preferences->Ant->Runtime`
- Classpath tab
- Click `Restore Defaults` button.

That happened to fix the issue for me.

Comment: No idea **why** this worked for me, but it did. Was desperate enough to try anything anyway...

Answer (score 3):

I'm using IBM RAD7 (which is based on Eclipse) and I was having exactly the same problem. After much fiddling I went to "External Tools" | JRE Tab | select "Run in same JRE", mine was set yo use the Webpshere JRE. Took a day to fix it! Nigel

Answer (score 1):

Another quick thing to look for... Check your VM memory specs... I was messing around with low memory settings and it caused the same issues as above...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the script using "External Tools Configuration" you should also check the following:

Open "External Tools Configuration" and select the launcher that starts the Ant script. In the tab "Common" make sure that "Allocate console (necessary for input)" is checked!

In my case it was not checked and was the reason why no console output was visible.