# Eclipse Ant Builder: no console output

Tags: eclipse, console, antbuilder

I have a problem getting the Eclipse Ant Builder (Project > Properties > Builders > New > Ant Builder) to work correctly with the console view. After a restart of Eclipse, the output of the Ant Builder is never captured in the console. The builder respectively the used ant file works correctly as I can see the expected result on the filesystem. Also during the build I can see the "launching delegate" status in the eclipse progress view, but unfortunately no output apprears in the console view.

Obviously I have enabled the console view. Also did I configure the Ant Builder with the option "Allocate Console".

I found some weird workaround to make it kinda work: I just open Project > Properties and click on the "Builders" menu on the left (I don't even have to edit the builder or something like that). From this point on, the console is displayed, and even the output from previous builds that was not shown is now displayed. But to do such a workflow everytime I freshly start eclipse is simply not acceptable.

I tried different versions of Eclipse, but the result is the same in both:

- JasperSoft Studio 6.1 (Eclipse Juno)
- Eclipse Mars with JasperSoft Studio plugin

Is this a known eclipse problem or did I configure something wrong?

Edit: I also tried invacating Ant with the "Program" instead of the "Ant Builder", but there is exactly the same problem. Seems to be a general eclipse builder problem?

Comment: Is the console content shown when you resize the view? If this is a redraw problem, it would be interesting to know which OS you're running on.

Comment: Resizing of the view doesn't do the trick. I also tried closing and reopening  the console view after the output happened, but that doesn't work either. It seems like the console is not initialized or existing before opening the "Builders" configuration.

Comment: See this answer, resetting the Runtime to the defaults may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457827/ant-build-scripts-totally-hangs-with-no-messages-in-console