# SocketTimeoutException when Ant building in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I had been having problems getting Eclipse to build some of my Ant scripts (some built fine, others didn't). Basically, I would get no output in the Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) console. My `build.xml` works fine with ant when I run it on the command line. I was able to find some output in `workspace/.metadata/.log` where I found the following error message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.launching 4 120 2016-03-03 09:58:38.197
!MESSAGE Error logged from Ant UI: 
!STACK 0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.RemoteAntBuildListener$ServerConnection.run(RemoteAntBuildListener.java:89)
```

which [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457827/ant-build-scripts-totally-hangs-with-no-messages-in-console) people have asked about on Stackoverflow.

The other odd thing I noticed was that there's a line of text right above the console showing which `java` which shows the version of `java` being used, and working scripts were different than non-working. Working ant build scripts were using `jdk1.7.0_79` whereas failed ones were using the `/System` installed 1.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why java 1.6 wasn't working for me, but eventually I found where I could change Java for ant builds. It's in `Run/External Tools/External Tools Configuration.../<select failing build>/JRE`. Oddly, after getting it to work and then trying to switch back to 1.6, it gives me the following message when running ant:

```
JRE version less than 1.7 is not supported.
```

so who knows why 1.6 was picked in the first place (maybe the project itself is 1.6) or why it didn't give me a warning!

Anyway, there seems to be several causes of the error I posted above, but here's something you can try.

Answer (score 3):

Have had almost the same problem on Eclipse Oxygen, Java 1.8 and Ant to deploy to tomcat7.
Eclipse’s Console doesn't output any error message. It just says „terminated“ when I clicked Run Ant on the build.xml file. WTF

To solve this I had to set everything to java 1.8 especially ant's runtime JRE . But the „Java Compiler“ -> „Compiler compliance level“ has to be set to java 1.7 only.
Actually it is pretty simple. Well classpath settings can be tricky sometimes ;) especially without any error message.

Do not forget to check your ANT_HOME settings: Eclipse -> Prefs ->  Runtime -> „Restore Defaults“ should be sufficient. (Eclipse comes with Ant 1.10.1 as default which requires Java8 at runtime.)

And: If it works for some build.xml-files only you are overriding your workspace settings with your ant-build process. To solve this: Click on „Run As“ -> „Ant Build **...** “ (NOT „Ant Build“) and check your classpath (for ant) and the JRE settings here to Java 1.8

Regards

Well simply check your ANT_HOME setting.

Comment: Similar solution for Eclipse Oxygen but I just downloaded standalone Ant 1.9.9 and switched ANT_HOME to point at that and all works again, so from my POV it appears to be a problem with Oxygen and the built-in Ant 1.10.